# Exporting whole page instead of specific Query to CSV file

Tags: php, sql

my goal is to create a page where after click on button I get possibility to download a `CSV` file which contains result of specific `SQL Statement`.

Here is my button:

```
<?php
if (Env::value('profile')){
echo "<form action='/profiles/?s=".$sys->id."&profile=".$_GET["profile"]."&submit=true' method='get' class='asholder' enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sys\" value=\"".$sys->id."\" />"; 
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"profile\" value=\"".$_GET["profile"]."\" />";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' class=\"button\" value='Generate CSV'>";
echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Here is my handler:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])){

    ob_end_clean();
    $q11="select * from profile";

    dump_csv($db, $q11, 'profile');

}
```

and here is my method which is supposed to create CSV file:

```
function csv_field($s)
{
    return str_replace('"', '""', str_replace("\r","\n", iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1250', $s)));
}

function dump_csv($db, $q, $fname)
{
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fname.csv\"");
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public'); 

    foreach ($db->query($q)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

        if (!$first_row++) {
            foreach ($row as $key => $value)
                echo csv_field($key).";";
            echo "\n";
        }

        foreach ($row as $key => $value)
            echo csv_field($value).";";
        echo "\n";

        //var_dump($row);
        //exit;
    }
}
```

And yes I do have `ob_start();` at the start of the page.

Problem is that instead of table with only result of the Query: `select * from profile` I got whole `HTML` code of the page in my `CSV`.

Can anyone point me where I am doing the mistake?

current output:

```
<form action='/?page=profile' method='post' class='asholder'>   

<table class='list questionaire'>   
<tr class='tabledesc'><th colspan='3'>person</th></tr>  

<tr class='columndesc'> 
"   <td style='width: 170px"    '>name</td>
"   <td style='width: 224px"    '>mith</td><td>
"   <div class='hint'>enter the name<br />" 
"   and role of person</b></div>"   
"   </td>"  
</tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: could you add some example text from the output CSV file?

Comment: I don't understand - there's no code to write to the CSV file, instead it just 'echo's the CSV data...and there are also 'echo's in the button code which will get mixed up with the data?

Comment: Ofcourse there is. in this loop     foreach ($db->query($q)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) { row is an array which contain whole result set